# Downloading right xml encoding with JSF

Tags: xml, jsf

The issue is the following.
There is xml file, created by DocumentBuilderFactory.
Then it is necessary to download this file with the browser.

The code is the following:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");

transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(sw));

String xml = sw.toString();//returns the whole XML but in String format.


HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) 
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
response.setContentType("text/xml");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=export.xml");
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(xml.getBytes());
out.flush();
```

When it is exported, I have the problem with non-Latin symbols. As an example, Cyrillic word is exported as \xED\xEE\xE2\ symbols. How to correct this?
The other part of file is exported correctly.

Comment: Are you sure your character encoding in the HttpServletResponse is set to UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

Encoding probably goes awry because of a mismatch between http response and the bytes you are writing to the output stream.

`xml.getBytes()` uses your platform default encoding. It may be UTF-8 or it may be something else, like iso-8859-5. Use `xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` instead.
Also, http response (HTML headers) must match that encoding. Specify it explicitly with the content type: `response.setContentType("text/xml; charset=utf-8");`

On the other hand, you could probably do just `out.print(xml)`, and ServletOutputStream should take care of all the encoding complexities.

Comment: Thanks. Actually this one helped: xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).